# How do I use view in android layout?

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

```
<view
    android:layout_marginTop="530dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"/>
```

If I use this code in android studio. I got some Rendering problems
Error:
Unable to inflate view tag without class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have given "view" instead of "View"

Comment: Thank u.It is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this one

```
<View
 android:layout_marginTop="530dp"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="2dp"/>
```

Hopefully this will help you

Comment: Thank u.It is very helpful.